# $a,b\in\mathbb R^2$, is it ok to define $[a,b]$ to be the segment connecting $a$ and $b$?

Tags: geometry, notation

How to denote higher dimensional segments?

For example, $a,b\in\mathbb R^2$, it is not necessarily that $a\leq b$. Is it ok to denote $[a,b]$ as the segment connecting $a$ and $b$?

Comment: In any vector space you can write $[a,b]$ for the segment $\{tb+(1-t)a: 0\leq t \leq 1\}$. But we should remember that in the real ljne there is special meaning to $[a,b]$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Will my notation make people believe that $b\geq a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you say that that's what you mean the first time you use it, then it's completely fine. It doesn't conflict with other common notation, and it's somewhat similar to the meaning we are used to.

Comment: This is actually quite common for complex numbers, especially when dealing with line integrals.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, because $2$ and $1$ aren't points in the (real) plane. When I say "conflict", I mean whether it could mean two different things at the same time.

Comment: @Arthur I think what Kavi said makes sense. He meant this notation is not same as the meaning we are used to in one-dimensional space. In one dimensional space it is implied that $b\geq a$.

Comment: @HighGPA Yes, it is implied. But in two-dimensional space, $\geq$ makes no sense. So nothing about it can be implied. We are implicitly released from that requirement, as it were.

Comment: Well, in two dimensions, it is common (at least in some branches) to use $a>b$ to imply $a_1>b_1$ and $a_2>b_2$, without defining first. You could say that this definition is less common than the definition in 1-D, but it still exists.

Comment: @HighGPA In that case, you would have big problems making line segments that go down and to the right. So it's better to avoid such things in this case. But yes, that is a somewhat common partial order.